# SEEMOUS 2014, Problem 1

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, determinant

I would like to post my solution to the first problem of SEEMOUS 2014, as I have not found any other solution on the internet regarding this problem and I want to confirm the validity of my approach.

Let n be a nonzero natural number and function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{*}$, such that $f(2014)=1-f(2013)$. If
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1+f(x_{1}) & f(x_{2}) & f(x_{3}) & ... & f(x_{n})\\ 
f(x_{1}) & 1+f(x_{2}) & f(x_{3}) & ... & f(x_{n})\\ 
f(x_{1}) & f(x_{2}) & 1+f(x_{3}) & ... & f(x_{n})\\ 
 ...& ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
f(x_{1}) & f(x_{2})& f(x_{3}) & ... & 1+f(x_{n})
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
then show that $f$ is not continuous.

In answers, I will proceed with my approach.

Comment: It isn't clear to me that the assumption is that this equation is supposed to hold for *all* natural numbers $n$.

Comment: This is how it was phrased in the official papers of the exam, as you can see in this link in the beginning of the page 24.https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/MATH206/Problems-2007-2020.pdf

Answer (score 1):

My solution: Let
$$A_{n}=\begin{vmatrix}
1+f(x_{1}) & f(x_{2}) & f(x_{3}) & ... & f(x_{n})\\ 
f(x_{1}) & 1+f(x_{2}) & f(x_{3}) & ... & f(x_{n})\\ 
f(x_{1}) & f(x_{2}) & 1+f(x_{3}) & ... & f(x_{n})\\ 
 ...& ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
f(x_{1}) & f(x_{2})& f(x_{3}) & ... & 1+f(x_{n})
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & ... & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & ... & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0\\ 
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
f(x_{1}) & f(x_{2}) & f(x_{3}) & ... & f(x_{n})+1
\end{vmatrix}=A_{n-1}+B_{n}$$
where $$B_{n}=\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0\\ 
1 & -1 & 0 & ... & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & ... & 0\\ 
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & ... &-1 
\end{vmatrix}\cdot(-1)^{n+1}f(x_{1})=(-1)^{n-1+n+1}f(x_{1})=f(x_{1})$$
so continuing this process we obtain $A_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})+1\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})+1=0$. If we assume that $f$ is continuous, then $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$.
From $f(2014)+f(2013)=1$, we take that at least one of $f(2013), f(2014)$ is greater that $0$, so $f(x)>0$, but from the latter relation we deduce that for some $i\in[1,n]$ $f(x_i)<0$, so $f(x)<0$, contradiction.
Therefore, the function $f$ is not continuous.
Any comment on my solution would be appreciated.